# Creating a opengl context on android for a worker thread with custom render loop

Tags: android, opengl-es

i have a game that i wrote using lwjgl and i'm trying to port it to android. How do you create an opengl context without using `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`? i want to use it in my old main thread that i'm changing to a worker thread without having to change the game loop.

Main loop psudocode:

```
init();
while(!done)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    renderAll();
    updateScreen();
    while(getNextInputEvent())
    {
        handleInputEvent();
    }
    moveAllObjects();
    SyncFrameRate();
}
shutdown();
```

Comment: Any update for your question?

Comment: @doev I've since rewritten the project in C++ and use [SDL](http://libsdl.org/), which already has an android port. I've abandoned the Java version. In case you want to try and do it without SDL, you should use EGL, which is what android uses internally.